# How to have different user 'types' (e.g. Customer, ProductReviewer) with Rails API (using Knock jwt)

Tags: authentication, rails-api, jwt

I'm using [Knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) with my Rails API app for jwt authentication.

I have 3 types of users.
 
1) Admin - I'm using ActiveAdmin and admin is set up using devise (and is working fine)
2) User - this is my standard customer, going to my website
 
3) Reviewer - this would be an employee of the website and will be reviewing things (e.g. writing comments and scoring), who would have access to content that the User wouldn't.

**I want to be able to differentiate between the User and the ProductReviewer.**

I've tried setting up a separate `user_token_controller` and `reviewer_token_controller`.

The problem is that when I make a get http request (from postman) to a controller than returns data with a jwt for either the reviewer or the user, from the controller I can access both the `current_product_reviewer` and `current_user` which to me, doesn't make sense. I'm expecting that I could only access the `current_user` or the `current_reviewer` based on which jwt I use (the one I got back from logging in the reviewer or the user)

**Steps to follow and the code:**

1. POST request to `http://localhost:3000/api/reviewer_token` (with the body params including valid password and email).

Response = jwt token.

2. GET request to `http://localhost:3000/api/reviewers` with jwt token from above included

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  scope '/api' do
    resources :reviewers
    resources :users
    post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
    post 'reviewer_token' => 'reviewer_token#create'
    post 'find_user' => 'users#find'
  end
end
```

Reviewers controller

```
class ReviewersController < ApiController
  def index
    # if I binding.pry here then I can access current_reviewer & current_user.
    # I'm expecting to only have access to current_reviewer (because that's what the jwt token is for)
  end
end
```

It looks as though when I make the request, it's searching for the User, as well as the Reviewer and I want it to only search and show the `current reviewer`